# Optimize loading of image in jsp page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I have a single login page which has a image which is around "900KB" and it takes time in getting displayed because of which the whole page is not displayed.
Is there any way out through which at least login id and pwd input fields are displayed at first.

Are there any jquery plugin  which can be used to show the progress of images being rendered on the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just finished to test and appreciate the following jQuery plugin [jQuery Lazy](http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/).

It is a simple solution to your needs.

```js
$("img.lazy").Lazy({
  combined: true,
  delay: 3000
});
```

```css
img.lazy {
  width: 700px;
  height: 467px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.lazy/0.6.4/jquery.lazy.min.js"></script>
<!--
  use the data-src attribute and not the src!!!
-->
<img class="lazy" data-src="http://pngimg.com/upload/bicycle_helmet_PNG9846.png" src="" />
```